# Bash script won't exit on ctrl d

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a simple bash script, and as per my assignment specifications, it is to terminate on ctrl-d. However, it doesn't do that, it just stops reading the current input and begins reading the next input. How can I fix that? Here's my script:

```
while true ; do
echo Please enter your full name:
read fullName
echo Please enter your street addres:
read streetAddress
echo Please enter your zip code, city, and state in that order:
read zip city state

echo $fullName > Name.txt
echo "$streetAddress  $city  $state  $zip" >> Locations.txt
echo $fullName >> "$zip".txt
echo $streetAddress >> "$zip".txt
echo "$city  $state  $zip" >> "$zip".txt
echo '' >> "$zip".txt
done
```

Comment: Control-D is only end of input. So you just signal that you finished **one** input and then continiue ina **while true**.  If you ever want to *break* out of that loop then you can change that while true to a 'while (some_condition)' and change that condition in the loop.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But how can I sry an exit condition based on ctrl d because that's my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I achieved the desired behavior:

```
notFinished=true
while $notFinished ; do
    echo Please enter your full name:
    while read fullName ; do
        echo Please enter your street addres:
        read streetAddress
        echo Please enter your zip code, city, and state in that order:
        read zip city state

        echo $fullName > Name.txt
        echo "$streetAddress  $city  $state  $zip" >> Locations.txt
        echo $fullName >> "$zip".txt
        echo $streetAddress >> "$zip".txt
        echo "$city  $state  $zip" >> "$zip".txt
        echo '' >> "$zip".txt
        continue 2
    done
    notFinished=false
done
```

Now when I press control-d the application exits just as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exit code from the `read` command.

```
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Exiting"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This would work but we aren't yet allowed to use while loops.